# How do I create a new MathContext?

Tags: javascript, bigdecimal

## Main question

I’m using [this BigDecimal](http://pastebin.ca/2099922), and I’m trying to create a new MathContext object to pass to BigDecimal’s `divide()` method. But everything I’ve tried throws exceptions saying that it’s undefined. Here are some examples of things I’ve tried that *don’t* work:

```
context = new MathContext();                            // ReferenceError: MathContext is not defined
context = new BigDecimal.MathContext();                 // TypeError: undefined is not a function
context = new BigDecimal.prototype.MathContext();       // TypeError: undefined is not a function
a = new BigDecimal('1'); context = new a.MathContext(); // TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? (By the way, every search engine I’ve tried is returning results for Java, not Javascript, despite the fact that my first keyword is `javascript`.)

## Background

I’m trying to solve [this question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8737489/713735). I’ve determined that the problem is that BigDecimal is rounding answers in a way I don’t want. In following the code with a debugger, it appears that I need to pass a MathContext object in as the second argument to the `divide()` method. Here’s the relevant snippet from my code (ignore the magic numbers for now):

```
// v1 and v2 are both of type BigDecimal.
v1 = v1.divide(v2, new MathContext(0, 0, false, 4));
```

Any other method of solving my problem would be acceptable, but I still want to understand why I can’t just do `new MathContext()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first example of just creating

```
context = new MathContext(...)
```

is the correct one. At least its working in my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvTr8/). I'm include the BigDecimal library direct from github with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js/master/build/BigDecimal-all-last.js"></script>
```

Comment: It turns out that you were using a later version than I was, and your version contained a relevant bugfix. Updating my version solved my problem.